# Azure function unable to install azure-identity dependencies

Tags: python, azure, terraform, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to install and azure function using the `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = <STORAGE_BLOB_URL>` approach with a python runtime and linux os to a dedicated subnet so as to eliminate public internet traffic.

the specific required installs are:

```
import logging
import os
import azure.functions as func
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, CredentialUnavailableError
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from azure.core.exceptions import ResourceNotFoundError, ClientAuthenticationError
```

Prior to uploading the function folder in zip format, I isolate the function folder through a virtual environment and install the complete requirements.txt:

```
azure-functions
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-secrets
pymssql
```

without error. A subsequent `func start` confirms this allows local deploy. I use a `freeze` command to isolate the versions and update my requirements.txt. I then install all of these dependencies and packages locally.

My own python runtime is also 3.10 64bit.

These are uploaded locally with the --upgrade flag specified.

```
pip install --target="./.python_packages/lib/site-packages" --upgrade -r requirements.txt
```

I then upload to blob storage and create the function app in a dedicated subnet with a `Microsfot.Storage` endpoint.

Despite this, looking at the function monitoring output, the error seems to show that it is still unable to resolve dependencies:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'x509' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust' (unknown location). Please check the requirements.txt file for the missing module. For more info, please refer the troubleshooting guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 387, in _handle__function_load_request func = loader.load_function( File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 48, in call raise extend_exception_message(e, message) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/utils/wrappers.py", line 44, in call return func(*args, **kwargs) File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.10/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/loader.py", line 194, in load_function mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed File "/home/site/wwwroot/function_folder/__init__.py", line 4, in <module> from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential, CredentialUnavailableError File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/__init__.py", line 10, in <module> from ._credentials import ( File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> from .authorization_code import AuthorizationCodeCredential File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_credentials/authorization_code.py", line 9, in <module> from .._internal.aad_client import AadClient File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/__init__.py", line 5, in <module> from .aad_client import AadClient File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/aad_client.py", line 11, in <module> from .aad_client_base import AadClientBase File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/aad_client_base.py", line 20, in <module> from .aadclient_certificate import AadClientCertificate File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/azure/identity/_internal/aadclient_certificate.py", line 7, in <module> from cryptography import x509 File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/x509/__init__.py", line 7, in <module> from cryptography.x509 import certificate_transparency File "/home/site/wwwroot/.python_packages/lib/site-packages/cryptography/x509/certificate_transparency.py", line 11, in <module> from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import x509 as rust_x509
```

My question is, is this a `azure-identity` `cryptography` dependency specific error that others have encountered and resolved or is there a different approach that must be taken when deploying a function to an azure function app, contrary to documentation?

note that the specific error message is:

```
Result: Failure Exception: ImportError: cannot import name 'x509' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust'
```

Additional application settings have been configured to facilitate a python runtime:

```
SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true
ENABLE_ORYX_BUILD = true
FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = true
```

note that as VNet integration is required, this is on a service plan of Basic, rather than consumption. I have tried using Kudu to literally SSH into the wwwroot and install the necessary libraries without any success. The error remains.

Comment: is your code working in locally?

Comment: Can you share your full code?

Comment: The subsequent code is not being hit due to this import error and won't be related. Are you referring to the construction and layout of the source function folder?

Comment: is `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = <STORAGE_BLOB_URL>` method compulsory for your requirement?

Comment: I am open to other solutions but the virtual network integration and disabling of public traffic is a must so a local exec solution is not really feasible without a rewiring to have the command come from a devops agent. Is there no way for this feasibly to work with `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE = <STORAGE_BLOB_URL>`

Answer (score 0):

- Install `setuptools-rust` and `cryptography`:

**requirements.txt:**

```
azure-functions
azure-core
azure-identity
azure-keyvault-secrets
pymssql
setuptools-rust
cryptography
```

- Add below code snippet in
  **function_app.py:**

```py
import azure.functions as func
from azure.core.exceptions import (ClientAuthenticationError,
                                   ResourceNotFoundError)
from azure.identity import CredentialUnavailableError, DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
from cryptography import utils
from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust import x509 as rust_x509
```

[image]

**References:**

[ImportError: cannot import name 'x509' from 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._rust](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/importerror-cannot-import-name-x509-from-cryptography-hazmat-bindings-rust/185882/8)